# Calculate the point closest to multiple rays

Tags: vectors, python

**My problem**

I start out with a set of rays (consisting of an origin and bearing), 2 or more. Each ray is a 'guess' as to the location of an object, but there's no guarantee it's a good guess, they may be pointing in very different directions.

*Note:* I am working in 3d space, but 2 dimensions can be assumed to make it easier. Ultimately, I would prefer to find a solution that will work in both spaces but at the moment the simplest solution wins.

Among this list of rays, I want to find the point with the minimum distance from each line. Essentially, the best 'guess' as to the location of the object should be that point.

Here's a (masterfully drawn) picture to clarify further:

[image]

**My Approach**

In thinking this through, I believe I must take this two rays at a time and find the line segment that represents the shortest distance between them. Once I have that line, find its midpoint. Do this for each pair of rays, until I have a collection of midpoints, which I will then average to find the closest point.

I am not 100% confident in this approach, since a pair of rays that are close to parallel will have an intercept very far away that will throw off the average.

I began implementing the solution from [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702174/1486966), but it gives me poor results when I restrict it to 2 dimensions (by setting the third dimension to the same value) and I'll be honest in saying that it was  bit over my head.  Images of my code and poor results is below.

**Question**

Is there an existing algorithm for this problem? If not, do you have any suggested approaches? I am out of my element here, but I need to find a solution and I appreciate your help!

***Solution:* Code based on Mauricio's Answer**

Using the Mauricio's answer and [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), I found a solution that works in 2D and 3D. I haven't explored all the different options for `least_squares`, but all tests indicate this is doing what I expect.

Here's an image of the performance, which is what I would expect from this:

[image]

Green is the 'guess', the black lines are the rays.

**Code**

I have only included the most important parts, namely the main function (`locate`) and the optimization function (`distance`).

`locate` takes in a list of rays and feeds them (as well as an initial guess) into a least squares optimizer.

`distance` is $F_i(P)$ from Mauricio's algorithm below, and just determines the distance (for each parameter) from the point to the projection of each ray.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares


def locate(rays):
    """
    Determine the closest point to an arbitrary number of rays, and optionally plot the results

    :param rays:    list of ray tuples (S, D) where S is the starting point & D is a unit vector
    :return:        scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult object from scipy.optimize.least_squares call
    """

    # Generate a starting position, the dimension-wise mean of each ray's starting position
    ray_start_positions = []
    for ray in rays:
        ray_start_positions.append(ray[0])
    starting_P = np.stack(ray_start_positions).mean(axis=0).ravel()

    # Start the least squares algorithm, passing the list of rays to our error function
    ans = least_squares(distance, starting_P, kwargs={'rays': rays})

    return ans


def distance(P, rays):
    """
    Calculate the distance between a point and each ray

    :param P:       1xd array representing coordinates of a point
    :param rays:    list of ray tuples (S, D) where S is the starting point & D is a unit vector
    :return:        nx1 array of closest distance from point P to each ray in rays
    """

    dims = len(rays[0][0][0])

    # Generate array to hold calculated error distances
    errors = np.full([len(rays)*dims,1], np.inf)

    # For each ray, calculate the error and put in the errors array
    for i, _ in enumerate(rays):
        S, D = rays[i]
        t_P = D.dot((P - S).T)/(D.dot(D.T))
        if t_P > 0:
            errors[i*dims:(i+1)*dims] = (P - (S + t_P * D)).T
        else:
            errors[i*dims:(i+1)*dims] = (P - S).T

    # Convert the error array to a vector (vs a nx1 matrix)
    return errors.ravel()
```

Comment: Not sure i understand the question.

Comment: @mathreadler I'll try to clarify the first section

Comment: One thing are lines (they are infinite in both directions), other thing are vectors (they do not have position, hence calculate distance does not make sense), other thing are line segments (which have two end points) and other thing are rays (they are line segments but have only one end point i.e.,  have start position and direction vector which extend infinitely) which one are you using?

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Rays, I'll update the question, thanks

Comment: I think you should feed $F_i(P)$ instead of $E_i(P)$ to the solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ray can be parameterized as $R(t) = S + t D$ where $S$ is the starting point, $D$ is the direction unit-vector and $t$ is a positive scalar.

The closest point on the ray to a point $P$ is the projection of the point on the ray or the point $S$ itself. The projection is given by:

$t_P = D \cdot (P - S) / (D \cdot D)$

The distance $E$ is:

$E = \| P - (S + t_P D) \|$ iff $t_P > 0$
$E = \| P - S \|$ iff $t_P \leq 0$

The problem to solve is then minimize the functional:

arg $\min_P \sum_i^n{ E_i(P)^2}$

The problem is linear least squares, however since the distance is piecewise function, probably will need to iterate on the solution using Gauss-Newton kind of solver until reaching covergence.

Let us define a function $F_i(P)$ that returns a column vector, such that $E_i(P)^2 =  F_i(P)^T   F_i(P)$. Such function is defined as:

$F(P) = P - (S + t_P D)$ iff $t_P > 0$
$F(P) = P - S$ iff $t_P \leq 0$

For using Gauss-Newton solver to find a solution you have to provide an starting point $P$ (that can be the average of ray locations), a $3n \times 1$ vector of errors (assuming 3D vectors are used), which is stacking the output of individual $F_i(P)$, and a $3n \times 3$ jacobian matrix, which is stacking the individual $3 \times 3$ jacobian matrix of $F_i(P)$.

Comment: This looks promising! So to proceed, you suggest I take a ray, and start projecting points from it onto another ray and use a solver to find the minimum?

Comment: I think you can write (or use) a Gauss-Newton solver to find a solution. For that we have to provide an starting point $P$ (that can be the average of ray locations), a $3n \times 1$ vector of errors, which is stacking the output of individual $E_i(P)$, and a $3n \times 3$ jacobian matrix, which is stacking the individual $3 \times 3$ jacobian matrix of $E_i(P)$.

Comment: Why is the error vector $3n$ instead of $n$? Should I be finding the error distance $E$ in each dimension?

Comment: False alarm - I have updated my question with progress I've made implementing your algorithm. Do you have any further suggestions for me? The optimization function seems to be working very poorly.

Comment: I have added a clarification to my answer, I dont know about that optimization package but maybe you are feeding the wrong function to it.

Comment: So I feel a bit silly, but my answer earlier actually worked (based off $E_i(P)$) but while plotting it, my axes were not uniform, so the skewness of the plot was making it look incorrect. I have implemented $F_i(P)$ anyway since I believe it will give me better results. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

More of a coder than a mathematician, but here's the approach I'd take:

First, write a function that takes an arbitrary point (x,y,z) and a collection of vectors - and then for each vector in the collection, calculate the closest distance from the point to the vector - and have it add up the squares of all those values.

The idea being that once that function is established, you can feed in a trial point and get a score (the lower, the better fit that particular point is.)

Next step is to program a recursive function, kinda like:

```
Point FindBestPoint(Point startingPoint, double testRange, Vectors vectors)
{
    Get scores for:
        startingPoint
        Each of the other 26 points of the cube:
            x+testRange,y,z
            x-testRange,y,z
            x,y+testRange,z
            x,y-testRange,z
            x-testRange,y-testRange,z
            etc
    if startingPoint had the lowest score:
        if (testRange is below your threshhold)
            return startingPoint
        else
            return FindBestPoint(startingPoint, testRange/2, vectors);
    Otherwise
        return FindBestPoint(pointWithLowestScore, testRange, vectors);
}
```

Call FindBestPoint with a startingPoint of 0,0,0, a testRange of an absurdly high value.  It'll recursively dig down to find the minima.

Comment: 'rootfinding' techniques like this don't work as well as you'd hope for finding minima even in one dimension, and they actually get _much_ worse in multiple dimensions - in particular, for problems like this that are 'minimize an energy based on many objects' there tend to be a lot of local minima that are very easy for 'naive' methods to fall into.